# Cant read xml nodes from namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, namespaces

Basically I have an XML file which resembles this:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-06-15">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.2345"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="10.1"/>
        </Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-06-16">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1596"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="9.546"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

And I insert it like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    fxRatesXml(xmlData, updatedOn)
SELECT 
    CONVERT(XML, bulkColumn), 
    GETDATE() 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'I:\Downloads\eurofxref-hist-90d.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as fxRateXmlData;
```

I then try to read the time, currency and rate like so:

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @sql NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT 
    @xml = xmlData
FROM 
    fxRatesXml

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml, '<root xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"/>'

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    OPENXML(@hDoc, 'gesmes:Cube')
WITH 
( 
    [time] nvarchar(max) 'Cube/time',
    currency nvarchar(max) 'Cube/Cube/currency',
    rate nvarchar(max) 'Cube/Cube/rate'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

but no luck.

I am not sure where I'm going wrong any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED**

Updated XML to be more specific. It can include more then just 2 cubes of time and more then 2 currencies per cube of time.

How would I iterate/select them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have populated the `@xml` variable, instead of using `EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument`, try to define the namespaces you need using `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES`:

I added the missing closing tag `</gesmes:Envelope>` at the end of the xml, so I tested my query with the following xml:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-06-15">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1596"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

This is the query to retrieve tha data from xml variable @`xml`:

```
declare @xml xml = '<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"> <Cube> <Cube time="2018-06-15"> <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1596"/> </Cube> </Cube> </gesmes:Envelope>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' AS gesmes,
                    'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref' as ns)
SELECT 
    T.X.value('ns:Cube[1]/@currency','varchar(500)') AS [currency],
    T.X.value('ns:Cube[1]/@rate','varchar(500)') AS [rate],
    T.X.value('./@time','varchar(500)') AS [time]
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/gesmes:Envelope/ns:Cube/ns:Cube') AS T(X)
```

Results:

[image]

To handle multiple `<Cube>` tags:

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-06-15">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.2345"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="10.1"/>
        </Cube>
        <Cube time="2018-06-16">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1596"/>
            <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="9.546"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

you can use this query:

```
declare @xml xml ='<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"> <Cube> <Cube time="2018-06-15"> <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.2345"/> <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="10.1"/> </Cube> <Cube time="2018-06-16"> <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1596"/> <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="9.546"/> </Cube> </Cube> </gesmes:Envelope>'    

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' AS gesmes,
    'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref' as ns)
SELECT T.X.value('(.)[1]/@currency','varchar(500)') AS [currency]
     ,T.X.value('(.)[1]/@rate','varchar(500)') AS [rate]
     ,T.X.value('(..)[1]/@time','varchar(500)') AS [time]
FROM @xml.nodes('/gesmes:Envelope/ns:Cube/ns:Cube/ns:Cube') AS T(X)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you, I did see the `WITH` clause method, but I guess I thought it would work either way! And sorry for the missing closing tag! Was in a rush! :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp You're welcome! I recently struggled a bit with xml namespaces in SQL Server, so it is a pleasure to share ;)

Comment: Lol yeah its been a headache many thanks. How would I iterate over multiple Cubes though? Sorry a bit confused on that, Like I have multiple currencies/rates per cube... and multiple cubes for different times

Comment: @DavidKroukamp which one of the 3 nested `<Cube>` tag appears multiple times?

Comment: Please see updated question (xml specifically), with that said it can include more then just 2 cubes of time and more then 2 currencies per cube of time